# What factors can cause variation in the output of a requests.get call? (getting inconsistent results when scraping Google Scholar)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-scholar

I'm trying to scrape a few pages on Google Scholar using Python. On the GS "View Article" page, the title of the article has a link article's web location, if one exists, and that link appears in the HTML at the location referenced in the code below.

However, running this from Colab, I only get the url some of the time. Other times, no link appears in the HTML, despite always appearing when inspecting the website via browser, even with javascript disabled. All the other elements I extract from the HTML are always present. What factors can cause this sort of inconsistency in HTML output?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
user_agent = 'Your User Agent'
r = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&citation_for_view=l9Or8EMAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C',  headers = {'User-agent': user_agent})
r_soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
try:
url = r_soup.find('a',class\_="gsc_oci_title_link")\['href'\]
except:
url = 'missing'
print(url)
```

Edit: here is a screenshot of the differing output
[image: diffchecker output for successful scrape (left) and unsuccessful (right)]

Comment: What is the page content on the occasions when the link is missing?  Perhaps GS decided that you are a robot (which is true!) and returned a different page asking you to  stop...

Comment: On the occasions when the link is not present, does the page content otherwise match what you expected to see?

Comment: The highlighted text in the screenshot are the only changes--excision of the paper links and the abstract. All the other content--citations per year, title, journal, etc are unchanged.

Comment: _excision of the paper links and the abstract_ Maybe that is how GS tells robots to shoo -- by leaving out the really important bits...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to get links to article sites. I suggest you use a similar solution selenium + BeautifulSoup. Here is the working code that will return all the links on the search page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url = f'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&citation_for_view=l9Or8EMAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
}

def get_result(url, headers):

    chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.binary_location = "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    executable_path=".../chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver") # the path to your chromedriver
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)  # You can wait until the page loads, but it's easier to wait 10 seconds, they will be enough with a margin
    html = driver.page_source
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    urls = soup.find_all('div', class_="gsc_oci_merged_snippet")
    for url in urls:
        url = f"https://scholar.google.com{url.find('a').get('href')}"
        print(url)


def main():
    get_result(url=url, headers=headers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&cluster=2551440091515661797&btnI=1&hl=en
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&cluster=10164968870686571448&btnI=1&hl=en
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&cluster=13511907351267264398&btnI=1&hl=en
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&cluster=728533604572740862&btnI=1&hl=en
```

I hope this is what you were looking for